# Equivariant and basic cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

I have difficulties to understand the connection between equivariant and basic cohomology. I understand the definition of them but not how they are related (the Weil algebra killed me :)).

For example, consider a smooth manifold $M$ with a smooth action of a Lie group $G$. If we assume all orbits have the same dimension, this induces a foliated structure on $M$ whose leaves are the orbites of the action. So, we have two cohomologies to look at: the basic and the equivariant ones. How are they related?

I have no special assumptions on $G$ and $M$. $G$ has no reason to be compact, and the action is not even proper (for example, the foliation of $S^1\times S^1$ induced by the foliation of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ by parallel lines of non rational slope is a case I would like to understand). In the special case I am looking, $G$ is commutative but I am also interested in what happens when $G$ is not.

Hope my question is not too trivial. If it is, please give me a good reference on the subject (with a differential geomety point of view if possible).

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**:  To answer a comment, here is the definition of basic cohomology Let $(M,F)$ be a foliated manifold. A basic form on M is a form $\omega$ satisfying $\iota_X\omega=0$ and ${\mathcal L}_X\omega=0$ for every vector field tangent to the foliation at every point. The exterior derivative d sends a basic form to a basic form, so the space $\Omega_{\textrm{bas}}(M)$ of basic forms is a differentiel complex. The basic cohomology is its cohomology ring. So, its coefficient ring is $\mathbb R$ and I am considering equivariant cohomology with the same ring.

Comment: Can you please recall for me what basic cohomology is, and maybe say which coefficients you consider.

Comment: Sorry for late answer (week-end...) and thank you for your interest in my question.

Let $(M,{\mathcal F})$ be a foliated manifold. A basic form on $M$ is a form $\omega$ satisfying $i_X\omega=0$ and $L_X\omega=0$ for every vector field tangent to the foliation at every point. The exterior derivative $d$ sends a basic form to a basic form, so the space  $\Omega_{bas}(M)$ of basic forms is a differentiel complex. The basic cohomology is its cohomology ring. So, its coefficient ring is $\mathbb R$ and I am considering equivariant cohomology with the same ring.


Comment: The Paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1043v1.pdf might be of interest to you, even though it does not exactly adress your question.

Comment: @user39082: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I already know this example. It deals with a mix of basic and equivariant cohomologies: a group action transverse to a foliation. But it is too complicated for me.

Comment: I would really really like it if people would not post links to the PDF of an arXiv e-print but to the abstract.

Comment: As per José Figueroa-O'Farrill's comment, here is link for arxiv abstract https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1043